# How to build leaflet.markercluster.js from GitHub source?

Tags: javascript, npm, leaflet

I would like to build the compiled javascript code of leaflet.markercluster from the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). I'm new to programming and would just like to learn how this is done. My understanding is that package.json can be run using grunt.js, but I see there is no gruntfile.js in the GitHub source.

I downloaded the project using `bower install leaflet.markercluster` and the project shows up in my local project folder in `bower_components/`

The `package.json` in `bower_components/leaflet.markercluster/` is

```
{
    "name": "leaflet.markercluster",
    "version": "0.4.0",
    "description": "Provides Beautiful Animated Marker Clustering functionality for Leaflet",
    "dependencies": {
        "leaflet": "~0.7.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "jshint": "~2.1.3",
        "mocha": "~1.10.0",
        "karma": "~0.8.5",
        "uglify-js": "~2.3.6",
        "jake": "~0.5.16"
    },
    "main": "dist/leaflet.markercluster.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jake test",
        "prepublish": "jake"
    },
    "keywords": ["gis", "map"]
}
```

How would I run `package.json` to build dist/leaflet.markercluster.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package.json` is for [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) (node package manager, as the tag added by Chris), not specifically Grunt.

You can follow these steps:

1) Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) *(probably already done since you use Bower)*.

2) Install [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) *(probably already done since you use Bower)*.

3) [Clone](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/) the repository onto your local drive: `git clone <git endpoint>` (in your case for Leaflet.markercluster: `git clone https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster.git`). *Maybe `bower install` is equivalent*.

4) Navigate to the newly created `Leaflet.markercluster` folder on your local drive.

5) **Run `npm install`**. The newly built compiled and minified JS files should appear in the "dist" sub-folder. Note that you will still need an Internet connection for this, as npm will download all dependencies and development dependencies when running this command.

Comment: So somebody thought I would go ahead and get linux and bloat it with NPM just because I need a Leaflet plugin? Such nice people

Comment: Hi @HCLivess, I do not see why you would conclude from the above that you need Linux. And why you would have to go through a build step if you just need a Leaflet plugin. Feel free to open a question should you need help.